# How to use proxies within browser_cookie3 or any similar library that helps grab cookies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, cookies

I'm trying to populate cookies from a domain using this library [browser_cookie3](https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3). It appears to be doing fine. **However, the only and main problem is that I can't figure out any way how to supply proxies within this library to get cookies from the location the proxy is from.**

For example, if I use this domain `www.nordstrom.com` within that library and execute the script below:

```
import browser_cookie3

cj = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='www.nordstrom.com')

for item in cj:
    if not 'internationalshippref' in item.name:
        continue
    cookie = f'{item.name}={item.value}'
    break

print(cookie)
```

I always get the following result as my current location is Bangladesh:

```
internationalshippref=preferredcountry=BD&preferredcurrency=BDT&preferredcountryname=Bangladesh
```

> How to get cookies from the above site using proxies within browser_cookie3 or any other library?

Comment: Is using the library necessary? You could achieve the same without it as well

Comment: Nope. I'm willing to go for any library as long as I can fetch cookies from that domain using proxies.

Comment: I have a solution, I'll post an answer soon. Can I know which OS you are using?

Comment: Sure. It's windows 10. Eagerly awaiting your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website has some basic security against scraping. But using **[playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)**, I was able to get to their website and get the cookies without much hassle. Follow this self-explanatory small sample to start the browser with proxies enabled and get the cookies:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def get_proxy(server, user=None, password=None):
    if user and password:
        return {'server': server, 'username': user, 'password': password}
    else:
        return {'server': server}


def get_cookies(user_agent, proxy=None):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=True, proxy=proxy)
        context = browser.new_context(no_viewport=True, user_agent=user_agent)
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://www.nordstrom.com")
        with page.expect_navigation(url="https://www.nordstrom.com/", wait_until='load'):
            pass
        cookies = context.cookies()
        browser.close()
    return cookies


proxy = get_proxy(server='http://my.server.com:8282', user='optional', password='optional')
print(get_cookies('my useragent', proxy))
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'rfx-forex-rate', 'value': 'currencyCode=USD&exchangeRate=1&quoteId=0', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1656083650, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'internationalshippref', 'value': 'preferredcountry=US&preferredcurrency=USD&preferredcountryname=United%20States', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971440050, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'no-track', 'value': 'ccpa=false', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971440050, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'nordstrom', 'value': 'bagcount=0&firstname=&ispinned=False&isSocial=False&shopperattr=||0|False|-1&shopperid=c38c25da4c2542fd873e7a88d0ba163f&USERNAME=', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971440050, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'nui', 'value': 'firstVisit=2022-06-24T14%3A14%3A10.457Z&geoLocation=&isModified=false&lme=false', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971440050, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'session', 'value': 'FILTERSTATE=&RESULTBACK=&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.nordstrom.com&SEARCHRETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.nordstrom.com&FLSEmployeeNumber=&FLSRegisterNumber=&FLSStoreNumber=&FLSPOSType=&gctoken=&CookieDomain=&IsStoreModeActive=0', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': -1, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'shoppertoken', 'value': 'shopperToken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjMzhjMjVkYTRjMjU0MmZkODczZTdhODhkMGJhMTYzZiIsImF1ZCI6Imd1ZXN0IiwiaXNzIjoibm9yZHN0cm9tLWd1ZXN0LWF1dGgiLCJleHAiOjE5NzE2OTkyNTAsInJlZnJlc2giOjE2NTYwOTQ0NTAsImp0aSI6IjA2YmE5M2I3LTA3ZjMtNDRkMi1iYjc4LTQwYzBjYWFiZWI4MSIsImlhdCI6MTY1NjA4MDA1MH0.jyAHIejISNgu_cGmZh7k9R7iiB7HEwwDLc9g5ek79fz71yQn34kuwERAG4lZf3laZPUXJgakl3L-DScPLJ4FJ9j_kNUxjuw2Eg4rk7hIPvZ35kIqwtwbkrO8XjyhjgxTeXyAV5HCZa8QFO263REuI0gA1y9-MFA2fyGME3uWQruwB_q_6hfeR-Nyq8epBOuBRRqttLY6sV0sXACzRyPciqR3ykochm90DwG3H2PU4cYts6OO0wFqrnM_LhcMzD2AmiK7XegdwwKBlwzJcRqoiXu_OZFoMHPI2_eW3FFfED8A93jPyGYKmFm_Hm4RpItibGG27TJJRY0HmaO_BvqxKA', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971397793, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'usersession', 'value': 'CookieDomain=nordstrom.com&SessionId=1029b2c9-bbc5-45db-8454-202c6271ad8f', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': -1, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'experiments', 'value': 'ExperimentId=789ff94f-d13c-4ebb-9303-433a542f3ae8', 'domain': '.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1971699250, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'Ad34bsY56', 'value': 'AxkjEJaBAQAAfjgIHurZtpHYD2QEPO5pusibS79jQ7brx8HiJfld2cp5Ie3MAUjwyyWcuJMswH8AAEB3AAAAAA|1|1|8421240d3766a87fc796cc577ffbc7cd05a87826', 'domain': '.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 3233927649, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}, {'name': 'Bd34bsY56', 'value': 'A6AoEJaBAQAANCRRvsL-3aoOFIk1xtv3Y6fYMRV0SY7IjL4nIEPc1ebkqh6SAUjwyyWcuJMswH8AAEB3AAAAAA==', 'domain': 'www.nordstrom.com', 'path': '/', 'expires': 1687637001, 'httpOnly': False, 'secure': True, 'sameSite': 'None'}]
```

Do keep in mind that calling `get_cookies` repeatedly is very inefficient, since it spawns a resource-heavy [browser](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/browsers) every time. If you do need to get cookies repeatedly, I would suggest using something like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to spawn another process, which keeps the browser alive inside it, and serves any request to get the cookies at the same time through queues.

**Note**:

About this line:

```
with page.expect_navigation(url="https://www.nordstrom.com/", wait_until='load'):
    pass
```

This is because the website uses automatic redirection through javascript if you visit it without setting the appropriate headers and cookies. Therefore, as soon as we enter the website the first time, we wait for a bit for the redirect to happen. Once it does, we will get the cookies we want.

**Update** : As per comments below, I updated the code above to pass an additional user-agent parameter.

Comment: Looks like your solution is capable of fetching cookies from that site. However, can you suggest me how to do the same using `chrome` instead of `firefox`?

Comment: @SMTH Chromium based browsers do not seem to work with the website. I have tried with Edge and all available channels for chrome, even after making it much harder to detect playwright. However, strangely, both Webkit based browsers and Firefox work, even with the the user agent of chromium ones. So if you want, you can supply the user agent of chrome browser while using firefox to get the relevant cookies (if they are affected by the type of browser anyway). Would that work?

Comment: @SMTH The website seems to produce cookies which only work with the same user-agent. Hence, user-agent should be same  during getting, and then using those cookies. Use the updated `get_cookies` function above and pass in the same user-agent when retrieving cookies and using those cookies in the headers to `request.get`. Also, it is better to give the sample code in the question itself so other people who stumble upon the question can understand and follow the discussion that happened ^^.

Comment: @SMTH, I hope you are only passing the `user`, and `password` parameters to `get_proxies`  if your proxy actually requires a username and password. If your proxy does not require them, then don't pass anything other than `server`. Also, this is getting really messy; please update your question with the exact details or errors you are receiving rather than commenting here since it's hard to debug like this.

Answer (score 0):

Browser Cookie library uses an SQLite database generated by your browser to create a cookie jar. You cannot explicitly specify a proxy through Python code since it does not run a browser on its own.

One solution would be to configure a browser-wide proxy and then execute your script.

You can configure a browser-wide proxy using Firefox, this option is not available in Chrome on some operating systems.